# Need help in mongodb settings in node app.js file for IBM bluemix deployment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ibm-cloud

```
I am trying to create a site and deploy in Bluemix,  using node.js, mongodb (mongolabs) which displays data from mongodb. I created a collection - "caterer", using mongolabs. My app.js is as below :

    var express = require('express'), 
    routes = require('./routes'), 
    cache = require('./routes/cache'), 
    http = require('http'), 
    path = require('path'), 
    mongodb = require('mongodb'), 
    url = require('url'); 
    var mongo = {}; 
    if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) { var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES); 
    if (env['mongodb-2.4']) 
    { mongo['url'] = env['mongodb-2.4'][0]['credentials']['uri']; } } 

    //With this as the connector var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient; var db = MongoClient.connect(mongo.url, function(err, db) 
    { if(err) { console.log("failed to connect to the database"); } 
    else { console.log("connected to database");}

app.get('/', function(req, res) 
{ mongodb.connect(mongo.url,function(err,conn)
{ var collection = db.get('caterer'); 
collection.find({},{},function(e,details)
{ res.render('index', { "details" : details }); }); }); });

when I push this to jazz hub, this is the error I see in Bluemix logs : BXNUI2034E: Error while getting instances resource. Cloud Foundry issued the following message: "Instance unavailable" See the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to check service status, review troubleshooting information, or for information about getting help.
```

This is the console output :

2014-11-19T03:15:57.88-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    2014-11-19T03:15:57.88-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    2014-11-19T03:15:57.88-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at node.js:902:3
    2014-11-19T03:15:57.96-0800 [API]     OUT App instance exited with guid 9dfd06e6-fc10-4207-881a-9557403160b3 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"9dfd06e6-fc10-4207-881a-9557403160b3", "version"=>"eab5d831-712a-4e8c-9426-cc01d0fd9a8e", "instance"=>"c5c734ba24ad4109b2befa60b3bc9790", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>8, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1416395757}
    2014-11-19T03:15:57.96-0800 [API]     OUT App instance exited with guid 9dfd06e6-fc10-4207-881a-9557403160b3 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"9dfd06e6-fc10-4207-881a-9557403160b3", "version"=>"eab5d831-712a-4e8c-9426-cc01d0fd9a8e", "instance"=>"c5c734ba24ad4109b2befa60b3bc9790", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>8, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1416395757}
    2014-11-19T03:15:57.98-0800 [DEA]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
    2014-11-19T03:34:44.31-0800 [DEA]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 9dfd06e6-fc10-4207-881a-9557403160b3
    2014-11-19T03:34:44.31-0800 [DEA]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 9dfd06e6-fc10-4207-881a-9557403160b3
    2014-11-19T03:40:44.55-0800 [DEA]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 9dfd06e6-fc10-4207-881a-9557403160b3
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0]   ERR 
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0]   ERR /home/vcap/app/app.js:86
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0]   ERR });
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0]   ERR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at startup (node.js:119:16)
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0]   ERR     at node.js:902:3
    2014-11-19T03:40:47.98-0800 [DEA]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections

Comment: Could you _please_ format your code? It is unreadable this way.

Comment: Am new to stack overflow, just formatted. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my code using Bluemix & MongoDB with  NodeExpress
a) http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/elements-of-crud-with-nodeexpress-and-mongodb-using-enide-studio/
b) http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/spicing-up-a-ibm-bluemix-cloud-app-with-mongodb-and-nodeexpress/

Also the best way to debug your app is i) using cf logs  --recent ii) Adding M & A service to your app

Regards
Ganesh

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the logs for cf push appname -recent:

```
2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0] ERR /home/vcap/app/app.js:86
2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0] ERR });
2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0] ERR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Its clearly seems issue with your app.js code at line number 86(syntax error).

Also,in case if you get any error for pushing your apps,please post details along with cf logs :)

Answer (score 0):

you can provide more details by running from the cf command line:

```
  cf logs <app_name> --recent
```

This should provide more information related to this error cause for investigation.

Comment: Can you please post your logs so we can debug what is going on?

Comment: 2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0] ERR /home/vcap/app/app.js:86 2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0] ERR }); 2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0] ERR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input  --->did you checked wats wrong here in syntax?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the JS code you posted. The error is crashing your app:

```
2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0] ERR /home/vcap/app/app.js:86
2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0] ERR });
2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0] ERR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Add this line to the end of your app.js file, which should fix it:

```
}); // end MongoClient.connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the log looks like there is syntax error in your app.js at line 86 which is resulting in compilation error of your error. Please check what code you have written at line 86 in app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

your cf logs are self explanatory to catch this error:

[App/0] ERR /home/vcap/app/app.js:86 2014-11-19T03:40:47.88-0800 [App/0] ERR }); 2014-11-19T03:40:47.89-0800 [App/0] ERR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Please correct your app.js code and again try to push it.